# Child List from Firebase with android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the value of my firebase tree

[image]

I got a class get_categories

```
public class get_categories {
    private String Name;

    public get_categories(){

    }

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then I declared the firebase

```
mRef = new Firebase("https://...../Users/Categories");
```

And try to retrieve my data with OnChildEventListener

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                //Log.e("VALUES " ,""+dataSnapshot.child("Details").getValue());
                get_categories getCatName = dataSnapshot.child("Details").getValue(get_categories.class);
                Log.e("NAME " ,""+getCatName.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

But I got an error

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Name" (class com.app.pierre.myapp.get_categories), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ]) at [Source: java.io.StringReader@9d0f705; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.app.pierre.myapp.get_categories["Name"])

What am I doing wrong ?

I used this case as reference: 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first change your Model like this,

```
public class GetCategories {
    private String Name;

    public GetCategories(){

    }

    public GetCategories(String name){
    this.Name = name;

    }

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and Push data using Model class Constructor..

```
GetCategories model = new GetCategories("yourValues");

mReference.child("Details").push().setValue(model);
```

and Now you can get it like this way..

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                GetCategories newPost = eventSnapshot.getValue(GetCategories.class);

                Log.e("NAME " ,""+ newPost.getName());   

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your solution, the thing is I don't need to push the data as I already got the data inside, but even if I used your method to set my data (with the model). When I call the listener I get an error message. Also my data is Categories/push()/Details/Name=value because in the example you gave me it was Categories/Details/push()/Name=value. Is there any alternative in my case to access the child of Details without knowing the parent of Details as it is auto-generate with the push() method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to retrieve data as i suggest in answer and just push as u were pushing.

Comment: as i know you can only get your data as i suggest coz i face the same problem and got data like this way

Comment: Well done !! I got it works !!! You don't know how much I'm happy.. I've been checking my code and documentation for the last 2 days !! Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the property on your JSON starts with an uppercase letter. But by the rules of JavaBean properties, `getName()` correspond to a property called `name` (with a lowercase n). So the two don't match up.

One way to get this working is to not use a setter, but instead use a public field:

```
public class get_categories {
    public String Name;
}
```

With this you're bypassing the JavaBean logic and get a direct mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Frank :)